# Why are the differences between my numbers inconsistent (sort of compund interest but not really)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, math

My code is supposed to generate an amount of xp required for each level, but on levels 6, 8 and 13 the difference between the xp needed for the previous level and the xp needed for the current level decrease. My code is as follows

```
const BASE_LVL_XP = 20;
let xp_collection = new Map();
for (let i = 1; i < 101; i ++) {
        // xp_collection.set(i, BASE_LVL_XP * .1);
        let amount = BASE_LVL_XP * (Math.ceil(Math.pow((1.1), (2 * i))) + i);
        xp_collection.set(i+1, amount);
    }
```

I'm also not 100% sure about the math, I kinda ripped it off of the compound interest formula

Comment: Hi. I cannot reproduce your issue. For i=1 to 13, I get these values: `3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22`

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified, my problem is that I never want the gap to decrease, but it does. For example, the gap between 5 and 7 is two, but the gap between 7 and 8 is one

Comment: That is very likely an artifact of rounding (Math.ceil)

Comment: You could avoid it by calculating the differences directly, rather than the values. Then when you round the differences, they're guaranteed to be nondecreasing. And then you add the differences to get the values.